# Dynamodb Update Item Expression with python boto3

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I have a string field, "title". I am trying to update it with the update expression with

```
persontable.update_item(Key={'person_id':person_id}, UpdateExpression="SET title = UPDATED")
```

and I get

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: The provided expression refers to an attribute that does not exist in the item
```

I can see the attribute "title" for that person in the AWS console. What gives?

Comment: This question solved it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586608/cant-update-item-in-dynamodb

Answer (score 13):

Don't plug the value into the expression directly.  Rather use *ExpressionAttributeValues* -- see [boto3 guide](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/dynamodb.html)

```
persontable.update_item(Key={'person_id':person_id},
                        UpdateExpression="SET title = :updated",                   
                        ExpressionAttributeValues={':updated': 'UPDATED'})
```

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to raise your content quality up

Comment: This answer solved my problem, where I was previously attempting to plug the value into the expression directly and my code errored out. Thank you!

Comment: why does AWS make this so complicated? i.e., why do we write out an arbitrary string that AWS CLI parses? seems like an overly complicated approach

Answer (score -1):

Check whether item has created properly before updating.

When the Table is not in "ACTIVE" state, if you try to put_item - it will not be created and next when when you try to update the same item which is not created. This error will occur.

Execute the put_item when the state is in "ACTIVE" state and then update item properly. You will not get this error.