# Why am is AWS Lambda returning "The provided key element does not match the schema" when I use my composite primary key?

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I'm new at AWS, and I'm trying to update an item attribute in DynamoDB via Lambda. I have tried code in Node.JS and Python and both attempts return:

> module initialization error: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema

Why is this happenning? Here is my table info:

- **Table name:** High_Holiday_Auctions
- **Primary partition key:** Aliyah_ID (String)
- **Primary sort key:** HighestBidder (String)

So I'm using both the partition key and the sort key in my code, so I can't figure out what is causing the error

**Lambda attempts with Python:**

```
    from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility
            import boto3
    import json
    import decimal

    # Helper class to convert a DynamoDB item to JSON.
    class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
        def default(self, o):
            if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
                if o % 1 > 0:
                    return float(o)
                else:
                    return int(o)
            return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)

    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1')

            table = dynamodb.Table('High_Holiday_Auctions')

            AliyahID = "YK_MaftirHaftarah"
            HighestBidder = "unclaimed"

            response = table.update_item(
                Key={
                    'AliyahID': AliyahID,
                    'HighestBidder': HighestBidder
                },
                UpdateExpression="set HighestBidder = :h, CurrentHighBid =:c,                              
    LastHighestBidder=:l",
                ExpressionAttributeValues={
                    ':h': "Harry S Truman",
                    ':c': "100",
                    ':l': "unclaimed"
                },
                ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
            )

            print("UpdateItem succeeded:")
            print(json.dumps(response, indent=4, cls=DecimalEncoder))
```

**Lambda attempts with Node.JS:**

```
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-east-1'});

    exports.handler = function index(event, context, callback) {
        var table = 'High_Holiday_Auctions';
        var   AliyahID = "YK_MaftirHaftarah";
        var  HighestBidder ="unclaimed"

            //updaate item unconditinoally
        var params ={
            TableName:table,
            Key:{
                "AliyahID": AliyahID,
            "HighestBidder": HighestBidder
            },
            UpdateExpression: "set HighestBidder =:h, CurrentHighBid =:c, LastHighestBidder=:l",
            ExpressionAttributeValues:{
                ":h":"George Burdell",
                ":c": "1000",
                ":l": "moe syslak"
            },

                ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
    };

    console.log("Updating the item...");
    docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to update item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        } else {
            console.log("UpdateItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        }
    });
    };
```

Similar existing questions that don't quite answer my issue:

- [can't update item in DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586608/cant-update-item-in-dynamodb)
- [Dynamodb Update Item Expression with python boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689912/dynamodb-update-item-expression-with-python-boto3)
- [DynamoDB - Key element does not match the schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506546/dynamodb-key-element-does-not-match-the-schema)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use only the primary partition key in the `Key` field to get the item to update unless your table uses composite primary key.

My guess is that the table you're trying to update that Item is configured with a simple primary key.

Comment: thanks! I've got a new error but at least this one is solved